# java vs scala - reading in file on a separate thread

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, concurrency, io

I would like to know what the best in terms of industry practice way is to read in a file using multithreaded approach. In Java I would do something of the following sort:

```
class Reader {  Result readFile(File file, Listener callback) }
class Listener { void process(Result r) }
```

Reader would spawn another thread to generate a result and then call back the `Listener` from withing the working thread. Would this be a good approach? How would this translate into Scala, which probably has other, better mechanisms to achieve this?

Comment: It's not clear (to me at least) whether you're trying to read one file or many.  If it's many files, then Kim Stebel's answer is better.  If it's a single file that needs results processed on different threads, then the other answer seems better.

Comment: What do you mean "better"? Shorter code? Probably yes. More performant? Probably not, as Scala generates a lot of code behind the scenes.

Comment: if he wants every line in the file processed concurrently, he can still do that with parallel collections.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach in Scala would be to use parallel collections. Say you have a sequence of files:

```
files:Seq[File] = ...
```

You can turn it into a parallel collection using `files.par` and then use map to do the processing. Map will internally use a thread pool to process parts of the sequence concurrently. What kind of thread pool is used can be [configured](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/configuration.html).

```
files.par.map(readFile).foreach(process)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it would be a good use case for [Akka](http://akka.io/) if you wanted an alternate approach.

Comment: Akka is just an actor framework and afaik can be used from Java. There are a lot of other actor framworks for java also.